# Failed to apply plugin 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

Tags: java, android, gradle, onesignal

i face this error when i try to open my project om android studio

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'.
> Could not create plugin of type 'GradleProjectPlugin'.
> > Could not initialize class com.onesignal.androidsdk.GradleProjectPlugin

i try: invalid cache

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when i update my android studio to giraffe,
I just changed my dependencies from :

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2'`

`classpath "gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.12.6"`

To:

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'`

`classpath "gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.13.4"`

Look here :
https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/issues/1399#issuecomment-889816863

Answer (score -1):

Check Dependencies and Versions.
Make sure you have the correct version of the OneSignal plugin and other related dependencies in your project's build.gradle files. Please verify that the plugin version matches your project's requirements.

Or, Update the Plugin.
If you're using an older version of the OneSignal plugin, try updating it to the latest version. Check the OneSignal documentation or GitHub repository for the latest version and instructions on how to update.

Comment: I don't know but I run the project last week it run smoothly but now I just get the error, i don't know may be because I change my PC